# Why does my washing machine leak only during the tumble dry cycle?

Tags: washing-machine

My Bosch Washer/Dryer WVF2402GB/01 Has started leaking a lot of water when tumble drying.
If dryer is left off it works normally.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Some condenser washer/dryers have a receptacle that you remove and empty. Check your machines user operating instructions for this system at first.